# Хороший стиль обработки ошибок

Tags: проектирование, исключения, java

Правильная и *хорошая* обработка ошибок и их генерация — довольно важная часть в разработке ПО. Но как это делать правильно и красиво — советов мало, и они очень поверхностны. Объясните, пожалуйста, принципы *хорошей* обработки ошибок (желательно в `Java`) вместе с примерами.

*UPD1*:

1. Когда делать `RuntimeException`, а когда просто `Exception`?
2. Единственен ли способ генерации ошибки оператором `throw`?
3. В каких лучше случаях создать, допустим, `MyException extends Exception`, а затем `MyOtherException extends MyException`? Иными словами, как увидеть необходимость в иерархии ошибок?
4. Когда делать примерно так:

   ```
   public void f() throws MyException {
       //некоторый код ...
       if (....){
           throw MyException(...);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Какие еще есть способы генерации ошибок?
6. Когда правильнее переносить ошибку на уровень функции (`... f() throws ...`)?

Comment: Да, но вопрос-то был в другом. Я не спрашивал, каким образом происходит генерация и отлов ошибок. Вопрос-то заключается в том, как хорошо проектировать удобную и качественную систему создания своих исключений, отлов их и т.д.

Comment: Тот, кто не умеет находить на это время - тот не умеет делать качественные продукты. Средства диагностики продукта в боевых условиях являются одним из показателей. Яркий пример - Windows: если что-то ломается, то ломается почти без слов.. и нет способа понять, что же произошло. Только гадать. Именно поэтому так часто приходится её переустанавливать.

Comment: Почитайте 9 главу классической книги [Effective Java Second Edition by Joshua Bloch](http://books.google.com/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC). Большинство вопросов, связанных с исключениями, там рассмотрены.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Windows это не самый удачный пример: существуют способы посмотреть подробную информацию о событиях в системе через тот же Event Viewer, если речь идёт именно о диагностике самой системы, а не конкретных приложений сторонних разработчиков.

Comment: Как правило информация там бесполезна, либо система находится в таком состоянии, что добраться до этого журнала не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Во-первых, как уже говорилось, используйте исключения. Создайте свою иерархию исключений и продумайте, какие из них сделать *runtime*, а какие нет. Никогда не используйте конструкции типа `new Exception(...)` или `new RuntimeException`. Вместо этого старайтесь создавать и кидать только адекватные ситуации исключения. Создание экземпляра `Exception` или `RuntimeException` — халтура и отписка вместо обработки ошибок.

Не забывайте проверять все параметры в конструкторах и, по возможности, в методах и своевременно кидать `IllegalArgumentException`. Пользуйтесь стандартными исключениями в соответствующих случаях. Используйте их по назначению и никогда не кидайте что попало.

Пользуйтесь `try`/`catch`/`finally`. Не забывайте уничтожать ресурсы.

Пользуйтесь логгерами, а не делайте `e.printStackTrace`. Никогда не делайте `catch` пустым, если только вы не уверены, что должны именно проигнорировать исключение.

При логгировании пользуйтесь по возможности полный метод `log` с уровнем логгирования, сообщением и исключением. Старайтесь в сообщении к логу описать, что именно упало и добавить какие-то сведения об условиях в блоке `try`. Это поможет выявить проблемы в боевых условиях. Старайтесь назначать адекватные уровни логгирования.

Настраивайте логгер. В некоторых случаях следует разделять логи для ошибок и варнингов. В противном случае сообщения об ошибках могут сротироваться и потеряться из-за менее важных сообщениях.

Подцепите что-то вроде аудита, если приложение серверное. Возможно стоит в особо фатальных случаях слать письмо админам.

Если это клиентское приложение на свинге, то можно отображать сообщение об ошибке с окне или в виде маленькой иконки в панели статуса.

**UPD1**

> Когда делать `RuntimeException`, а когда просто `Exception`?

Это довольно сложный вопрос и трудно дать общие рекомендации. Но в общем случае следует руководствоваться фатальностью ошибки и её вероятности возникновения. Также следует учитывать возможное расстояние от места генерирования ошибки до места фактической обработки. Например, `IOException` нельзя просто никак не обработать и это верно. Если его не обработать, то могут застрять какие-то ресурсы. И обычно обработка такой ошибки находится сравнительно близко от места её возникновения. В то же время `IllegalArgumentException` можно не отлавливать... так как обычно это ошибки, связанные с неправильным использованием API, неверное конфигурацией или недостаточной валидацией данных от пользователя. И попытка ловить такие исключения всюду привела бы к краху: код стал бы просто нечитаем. Иными словами, требуется здравый смысл.

> Единственен ли способ генерации ошибки оператором `throw`?

Нет, исключение не обязательно кидать. Например, в GWT (и не только) имеется интерфейс [`AsyncCallback`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html), который имеет метод `onError`, принимающий исключение в качестве параметра. Соответствующий код не кидает исключение через `throw`, а просто вызывает callback-метод и передаёт туда исключение. А уж callback сам решит, что с этим исключением делать.

> В каких лучше случаях создать, допустим, `MyException extends Exception`, а затем `MyOtherException extends MyException`? Иными словами, как увидеть необходимость в иерархии ошибок?

Очевидно в тех случаях, когда между исключениями могут быть какие-то «родственные» связи. Когда какие-то группы исключений имеют что-то общее.

> Когда делать примерно так:
>
> ```
> public void f() throws MyException {
>       //некоторый код ...
>       if (....){
>           throw MyException(...);
>       }
>   }
> ```

Всегда, когда `if` позволяет определить, что что-то пошло не по плану.

> Какие еще есть способы генерации ошибок?

Собственно, `assert`, `throw`и просто вызов обработчика с параметром-исключением.

> Когда правильнее переносить ошибку на уровень функции (`... f() throws ...`)?

Опять же лучший пример — `IOException`. Так следует делать всегда, когда есть ошибка, но вы точно знаете, что клиент (вызывающий ваш метод) может захотеть узнать об ошибке явно, а не по косвенным признакам. Так, например, если кто-то читает из сокета, то он хочет знать, что чтение невозможно и просто предвать операцию вместо того, чтобы каждый раз проверять, работает ли сокет или лепить бесконечные `if`-ы проверяя код ошибки после каждого метода read.

**UPD**

Да, пожалуй, по моему мнению, хорошим примером неправильного выбора между `Exception` и `RuntimeException` является `InterruptedException`. Было бы гораздо лучше, если бы он был `Runtime`. В результате либо всюду приходится его ловить и игнорировать, либо везде пробрасывать.. продумывая кейз, который никогда не произойдёт. И эти загромождения сильно портят код.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за неграмотность, а что можно вместо `new Exception(...) или new RuntimeException` ???

Comment: throw new SomeConcreteAndAdequateException

Comment: Спасибо за вразумительные и поучительные ответы! Наверное, из общих советов, больше нечего добавить. Остальное за опытом?

Comment: Боюсь что да :)

Comment: `вызывает callback-метод и передаёт туда исключение. А уж callback сам решит, что с этим исключением делать.`  
ДА ЭТО ГЕНИАЛЬНЫЙ СПОСОБ !!!!!

Comment: Я бы оценил этот способ более сдержано, но это как раз то что надо в случае асинхронной обработки.