# Обработка ошибок: реализация текстовых сообщений и не только, поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста

Tags: c#, winforms, логирование

Заранее прошу прощения за несколько размытый вопрос, который может иметь, пожалуй, несколько ответов, но всё-таки интересует прежде всего, практический аспект.

Итак, имеется некий не очень большой проект, состоящий из ряда независимых модулей, каждый вполне себе самостоятельный и написан разными людьми в разное время.

Часто в коде вижу различные (что естественно, imho) варианты отлова ошибок, от вполне годных и уместных до просто `try{...} catch{MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");}` (Да, и не такое бывает), часто критичные места вообще без блоков `try`.

Задача стоит привести это дело (обработку ошибок) к какому-либо стандарту, хотя бы в рамках данного проекта, и тут начинается веселье - во многих местах встречаются повторяющиеся операции, например, при работе с файлами и каталогами, и в таких местах часто приходится либо писать, либо уже есть конструкции вида:

```
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(path, "Путь к каталогу должен быть задан.");
        }
```

Или же есть аналогичные конструкции, где при ошибочной ситуации возбуждается исключение какого-либо типа (например, `IOException`) с каким-то текстовым описанием. При этом внутри проекта нет (почти нет, честно говоря) какой-то своей иерархии классов для обработки ошибок, используются штатные ошибки в основном.

Так вот, изначально был интересен взгляд на общую инфраструктуру обработки ошибок, и подход в целом. Но этот аспект [**уже прояснил**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/34825/222168) для себя.

Но пока не очень понимаю, **каким был бы наилучший подход с генерацией текстовых сообщений ошибок как для модулей самого проекта, так и для логгера?** (используется логгер, умеющий работать с экземплярами `Exception`).

Пока первое, что пришло на ум - вынести все сообщения в отдельный файл в виде констант и использовать их, подключая файл к каждому из модулей. Или может быть загнать всё в ресурсы?

Но в целом интересны мнения сообщества, какие еще практические реализации и подходы, методики были бы уместны и удобны в повседневном использовании с учетом описанного контекста? Возможно, есть какие-то более эффективные, удобные и проверенные способы или средства?

P.S.

1. Локализации проекта на несколько языков — *пока* нет.
2. Вносить существенные изменения в код модулей не очень хотелось бы ("малой кровью" обойтись бы).
3. Хотелось бы избежать сторонних решений, если, конечно они не решают задачу системно и применимы в дальнейшем (вспомнился EurekaLog в Delphi).

Спасибо за внимание к вопросу!

Comment: Надо разделить сообщения на 2 типа: сообщения для пользователя программы, которые лучше хранить в ресурсах хотя бы с точки зрения возможной локализации, и сообщения для программиста, которые как правило тяжело выносить куда-то отдельно потому, что неудобно, да и лучше их держать "по месту, под рукой". Плюс вы не забывайте про юниттесты: ведь примерно на каждый метод будет несколько тестов среди которых будут и специально вызывающие исключения (к примеру неверные параметры на входе).

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо! Комментарий по делу, и учел то, о чем я совсем забыл - про тестирование.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибки нужно отлавливать try/catch/finaly только в тех местах где они ожидаемы и только тех типов, которые ожидаются, банальный пример обращение к методу, в методе проверка на, к примеру, доступность этого вызова текущему пользователю, ожидаемое исключение скажем PermitionDeniedException, в блоке catch его и нужно отлавливать, остальное (например ArgumentNullException) должно пробрасываться на верх стека и обрабатывать "глобально", возможно тотальным крахом приложения.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PermitionDeniedException : System.Exception
{
     public PermitionDeniedException() : base("Пользователю не доступен этот метод") { }
     public PermitionDeniedException(string message) : base(message) { }
     public PermitionDeniedException(string message, Exception inner ) : base( message, inner ) { }
     protected PermitionDeniedException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info,context ) { }
}

try
{
    SomeMethod();
}
catch (PermitionDeniedException ex)
{
    _logger.Error(ex, "Сообщение")
}

private static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.ExceptionObject;        
    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(ExceptionType1))
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Сообщение");
        // TODO: Уведомить пользователя
    }
    else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(ExceptionType2))
    {
        _logger.Fatal(ex, "Сообщение");
        // Экстренно завершить приложение
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.Fatal(ex, "Сообщение");
        // Можно сделать дамп и завершить приложение
    }
}
```

Для Winforms, где-то в методе Main наверное стоит подписать на  [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) 
Например так: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;`
В обработчике UnhandledExceptionTrapper можно получить тип исключения, проверить его критичность и в зависимости от нее (критичности) либо экстренно свалиться, сообщив пользователю что то вроде "Программа выполнила недопустимую ошибку и будет закрыта" или же продолжить работу, но опять же известив пользователя. Что касается мультиязычности, то тут нужны динамические ресурсы и словари ресурсов, в них можно хранить строки, которыми можно описать исключение.

П.С. Структуру исключении стоит продумать, она может быть и одноуровневой, что скорее даже плюс. Максимально общие (корни) необходимо наследовать от [System.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx), что писать в сообщении придумать тоже не сложно, если у вас продуманная структура исключений.

Для логирования ошибок лучше всего использовать готовые логгеры, или Trace. Последний не такой гибкий, зато ничего из nuget тащить не нужно. Из готовых последнее время сам пользуюсь NLog.

Несколько сумбурно на мой взгляд, поэтому буду рад критике.

Comment: Лично с моей стороны критики не будет - все понятно на словах, и по коду тоже. Не забыли про логгер, но это другой момент (пока используется простенький класс для логирования, дальше - будем посмотреть, помимо NLog есть еще Log4net из известных, но с ним пока не доводилось работать).
Большое спасибо за ответ! Пока не принимаю его лишь потому, что есть корыстный интерес :-) просто — хотелось бы услышать больше мнений, но пятница, вечер...

Comment: @BlackWitcher log4net не использую только по тому, что его вроде забросили, а с nlog сейчас хочу сляпать пару таргетов засунуть в код и сделать зависимость от какого нибудь простенького интерфейса с конфигами и вытащить в нугет пакет, но комрады почемуто не слушают, не хотят использовать мой код в новых проектах, каждый раз систему логирования пилят новую, как и наборы исключений :) А так всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Мысль интересная, а, как на мой взгляд - главное, что полезная. Если есть довольно проработанный код, который решает ту или иную проблему (в данном случае логирование), так почему бы и не использовать? Да тем более с конфигами, настраиваемую, и с заготовкой наборов исключений, которые можно было бы дополнить собственными, в случае нужды. Я, например, использовал бы с удовольствием такое и в продакшне, так что если оформите как nuget-пакет, то, надеюсь, поделитесь с сообществом?

Comment: @BlackWitcher Да я про кухню на работе... А так у меня пока даже на гитхабе помоему акаунта нету)

Comment: я понял, что речь о работе, но если не жалко — то почему бы и не вынести полезное в массы? А аккаунты - дело наживное :)